# Error when installing IPA on older iOS devices: Failed to find matching arch for 64-bit Mach-O input file

Tags: ios

Getting these errors when installing IPA on older iOS devices (iOS 9 / iOS 10)

Error when installing IPA on older iOS devices: Failed to find matching arch for 64-bit Mach-O input file 
/private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Iv52UU/extracted/Payload/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I think it is because you are installing a 64-bit program on a 32-bit device.